# Rails get nested attribute based in has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many

I have 3 classes

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :dogs

end

Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :tags

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

I've tried execute `User.dogs` and I get a list of Dog entities like this:

```
[Dog, Dog, Dog, Dog]
```

If I access to a Dog entity in the array, I get all the attributes of Dog and works fine. But my problem it's that I need include Tag entity inside Dog.

By example if i do this

```
user.dogs.each do |dog_entity|
   puts dog_entity.tags #Prints the tags related value of Tag in Dog.
 end
```

**How achieves that when i execute `User.dogs` the Tag related value to Dog come inside in each Dog in the array?**

Answer (score 1):

`dogs` is association so you should call it on object not on model.

I think this should work

```
user.dogs.includes(:tags).each do |dog|
  puts dog.tags
end
```

Notice that `user` is object not model.
`includes(:tags)` allows us to avoid *n+1* problem.

Please also notice that model should have singular name, i.e. `Dog` not `Dogs`.